# Netsuite: Creating Usage Report by Period

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a saved search that gives the quantity/sales amount in NetSuite for the previous months to track usage on an item, customer and sales rep level. I have somewhat of a solution however the way my formula is set up it is going off of the system date rather than the whole previous month(s). For example, if I ran the search today it would give me the usage from today (Feb 7) back to Jan 7, Dec 7 and Nov 7. But I know NetSuite has 'Period' as a date function and struggling to incorporate that instead.

My formula is below for an example.

NULLIF(CASE WHEN {trandate} > **ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)** THEN CASE WHEN {type} = 'Invoice' THEN NVL({amount},0)*1 ELSE 0 END ELSE 0 END,0)

**ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1) <---I change this to -2 and -3 to show previous 2 and 3 months as well**

I am attempting to avoid doing 12 of these as a CASE WHEN posting period = P1 2021 THEN amount etc etc so we can have more of a rolling sales/quantity search.

Does not seem like NetSuite likes having to pull a point in time value, it likes to base searches/reports from the time it is run. But that could be being new'ish to NetSuite as we converted a few months ago.

[Output of the saved search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZMcf.png)

[Results with grouping and summarizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViYj5.png)

Comment: Are you grouping your periods or filtering or something else? Can you include a screenshot so we better understand the end result?

Comment: Hey Nathan, appreciate the reply. I attached two pictures, the end results that NetSuite outputs and then the "results" screen from the saved search. Grouping on the Items then the formula results. I guess don't necessarily need to be the periods, but more so the months. I am trying to learn a little more on the data formulas, anything to take the full month results rather than the Feb 7 - Jan 7 - Dec 7 etc etc.

Comment: Thanks, FYI, the SUM() inside you formula is superfluous unless performing additional calculations (i.e. SUM({amount}) / SUM({quantity}))

Answer (score 0):

**TRUNC(**ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)**,'Month')**-1